# Выбор между "на основе" и "на базе"

Tags: семантика

Исходя из сходства в их лексических значениях, интересно было бы узнать, в каких контекстах употребляется сочетание "на базе", а в каких "на основе"? И тот, и другой оборот означают некий принцип, учение, постулат, материал, из которого было что-то создано, сконструировано, организовано.

Страх на основе/на базе психических атак.

Comment: Та же разница, что между основываясь/базируясь. А в вашем примере нужно "на почве".

Comment: А чем отличается "базируясь" от "основываясь"?

Comment: В словаре указано, что это то же самое. Посмотрите примеры в интернете. Может, уловите разницу. Можно ещё посмотреть в словарях разницу между основа/база.